# Transition and Animation for Horizontal website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a horizontal website. And i want to apply the transitions and animations to the elements when they display on the screen. But now, at the loading of the page itself all the transitions and animations are applying for all elements. I tried (:visible) but it didn't work. So please guide me how to apply transition to elements when they display on screen.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: along with `:visible` you have to check whether element is in viewPort (visible on device screen) or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether DOM element is visible in current viewport or not.

```
function isElementInViewport(el) {
          var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
          if(rect.width!=0&&rect.height!=0&&$('#timeline').is(":visible")) {
            return (
                    rect.top > 0 &&
                    rect.left > 0 &&
                    rect.bottom < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
                    rect.right < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
            );
          }else{
            return false;
          }
        }
```

pass HTMLElement as an argument to this function and it will return whether it is visible in the current viewport or not.

Fire events to recheck the condition

```
window.addEventListener("load", function-tocheck-viewport-visibility);
window.addEventListener("resize", function-tocheck-viewport-visibility);
window.addEventListener("scroll", function-tocheck-viewport-visibility);
```